# Representation matrix with only $0$s and $1$s on the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

For any linear transformation $T$, is it possible to have a representation matrix with only $0$s and $1$s on the main diagonal and $0$s elsewhere?

Comment: Left multiplication by any such matrix defines a linear transformation. With respect to the same basis, that transformation will be represented by the original matrix.

Comment: @walkar Do you mean left multiply T by any such matrix?

Comment: Not quite. Take a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ in the form you want -- with only 0s and 1s on the main diagonal and 0s elsewhere. Multiplying a vector from $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $A$ defines a linear transformation $L_A: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Then the matrix representation of $L_A$ is just $A$ itself and so has the form you desire.

Comment: @walkar given any linear transformation T, how do I find such matrix? For example, given T from V to W, how do I find two basis for V and W such that the representative matrix has only 0 and 1 on thr main diagonal?

Comment: I misunderstood your question, sorry. You want to start with a fixed $T$ and then choose a basis so that it's of this form is that correct?

Comment: @walkar Yes exactly

Comment: Is $T$ an endomorphism, i.e., $T:V\to V$, so that the matrix of $T$ is square, or is $T$ a general linear transformation $T:V\to W$? It seems from one of your comments that it’s the latter, but the answer you accepted only covers endomorphisms. In addition, even for an endomorphism, if you don’t require the “input” and “output” bases to be the same, then the answer is rather different than the one you’ve accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is that it is not always possible to do so.

Any two representative matrices of the same linear transformation are *similar*, that is, $A$ is similar to $B$ if there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A=P^{-1}BP$.

The matrix you describe is a diagonal matrix -- one with entries only on the main diagonal. A matrix is diagonalizable if it is similar to a diagonal matrix. Unfortunately, not all matrices are diagonalizable. An example is the matrix $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1
\end{array} \right)$.

Hence left multiplication by this matrix $A$ is a linear transformation which doesn't have the required form.

Comment: Diagonalizability is insufficient as well. The matrix $A=\small\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&1}$ is already diagonal, but there’s no $P$ for which $P^{-1}AP$ has the form sought in the question. (Yes, I realize that the OP accepted your answer.)

Answer (score 0):

[The answer given by walkar](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2369688/265466) seems correct as far as it goes, but it covers only the specific case of an endomorphism $T:V\to V$ and using the same basis for both the “input” and “output” sides, i.e., for the matrix $[T]_\beta^\beta$, where $\beta$ is some ordered basis of $V$. However, the matrix $A=\small\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&1}$ is already diagonal, but there is no invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ has only zeros and ones on the main diagonal and zeros everywhere else, so it seems that even diagonalizability is itself insufficient.

Based on your comments, it seems to me that you were asking a rather different and broader question, anyway: Given $T:V\to W$, can one find bases $\beta$ and $\gamma$ of $V$ and $W$, respectively, such that $[T]_\gamma^\beta$ has only ones and zeros on its main diagonal and zeros everywhere else? The answer is yes, and it’s fairly easy to construct such bases if you recall that the columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the domain basis vectors.

To put this question in more concrete terms, let $\dim V=N$, $\dim W=M$, and $\operatorname{rank}T=\dim\operatorname{im}T=r\le\min(m,n)$. We seek bases $\beta$ and $\gamma$ such that $$[T]_\gamma^\beta=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}I_r & 0_{r\times(n-r)} \\ \hline 0_{(m-r)\times r} & 0_{(m-r)\times(n-r)}\end{array}\right].$$ The last $n-r$ columns of this matrix are zero, which means that all of those basis vectors must lie in the kernel of $T$. We know from the rank-nullity theorem that $\dim\ker T=n-r$, so choose for $v_{r+1},\dots,v_n\in\beta$ any basis of $\ker T$. This takes care of the last $n-r$ columns of $[T]_\gamma^\beta$. For the remaining elements of $\beta$, use any extension of the chosen kernel basis to a complete basis for $V$. A convenient choice in practice is a basis for the orthogonal complement of $\ker T$. The first $r$ columns of $[T]_\gamma^\beta$ tell us that $v_1,\dots,v_r$ are mapped by $T$ to the first $r$ elements of the ordered basis $\gamma$ of $W$, so set $w_i=Tv_i$ for $1\le i\le r$. (I’ll leave proving that these vectors are linearly independent to you.) This takes care of the first $r$ columns of $[T]_\gamma^\beta$. All that remains to do is to complete $\gamma=(w_1,\dots,w_r,w_{r+1},\dots,w_m)$ to a basis for $W$ with another $m-r$ linearly independent vectors. This is an arbitrary choice that has no effect whatsoever on $[T]_\gamma^\beta$.