# Find the basis $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of $R^3$ and $P_3(R)$ respectibly such that $[T]^\beta _\alpha$ is a diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Let $T:\mathbf{R}^3 -> P_3(\mathbf{R})$ the linear transformation given by $T(a,b,c)=(a-c)x^2+bx$

Find the basis $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of $R^3$ and $P_3(\mathbf{R})$ respectibly such that $[T]^\beta _\alpha$ is a diagonal matrix.

Well I know that the matrix given by the basis of eigenvectors will be diagonal. But I want to find a shorter way. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is $R$ here?

Comment: Real numbers. Sorry

Comment: Type it in an unambiguous way (`\mathbf{R}` or `\mathbb{R}`). Usually $R$ denotes a general ring.

Comment: What eigenvectors? Elements of the domain are triples of real numbers while elements of the codomain are polynomials. There is no triple of real numbers that is a polynomial, so how are you going to have $T(x)=\lambda x$? Instead, try looking for a basis of $\mathbb R^3$ and another for $P_3(\mathbb R)$ such that the matrix of $T$ Is of the form $\operatorname{diag}(1,\dots,1,0,\dots,0)$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2369676/265466. Might even be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

1. Observe that the kernel of $T$ is the span of $(1,0,1)^T$.
2. The matrix of $T$ in a pair of bases $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3),\ (\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3)$ is $\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}$ iff
   $$T(\alpha_1)=\beta_1,\ \ T(\alpha_2)=\beta_2,\ \ T(\alpha_3)=0\,.$$